# Django prefetch_related with m2m through relationship

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have the following models

```
class Film(models.Model):
    crew = models.ManyToManyField('Person', through='Role', blank=True)

class Role(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey('Person')
    film = models.ForeignKey('Film')
    person_role = models.ForeignKey(RoleType)
    credit = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    credited_as = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class RoleType(models.Model):
    """Actor, director, makeup artist..."""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Person(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=30, unique=True, null=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

A `Film`("Star Wars: The Clone Wars") has several `Person`("Christopher Lee"), each one of them can have one or more `Role`("Voice of Count Dooku") and every `Role` has a `RoleType`("Voice actor").

I'm using a DetailView to display the `Film`

```
class FilmDetail(DetailView):
    model = Film
```

In my template i'm showing all the Persons, so each time I show a Film 609 queries are being executed. To reduce this I want to use `prefetch_related` so I changed the view to:

```
class FilmDetail(DetailView):
    model = Film

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(FilmDetail, self).get_queryset().prefetch_related('crew')
```

But this didn't reduce the number of queries(610), I tried the following parameters to prefetch related and it didn't work:

```
def get_queryset(self):
        return super(FilmDetail, self).get_queryset().prefetch_related('crew__person_role')
```

I got an `Cannot find 'person_role' on Person object, 'crew__person_role' is an invalid parameter to prefetch_related()`error

What can I do to prefetch the `Person.full_name` and `slug` and all `Role` fields from `Film.crew`?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can construct your queryset like this:

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch

def get_queryset(self):
    return super(FilmDetail, self).get_queryset().prefetch_related(
        Prefetch(
            'crew',
            queryset=Role.objects.select_related(
                'person',
                'person_role',
            ),
        ),
    )
```

Only Film->Role is a backwards relation loadable with `prefetch_related`. Role->RoleType and Role->Person are forwards relations that you load with `select_related`.

Answer (score 2):

For those stumbling upon this in 2024, it seems there are better ways now:

```py
class FilmDetail(DetailView):
    model = Film

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(FilmDetail, self).get_queryset().prefetch_related(
            'role_set',
            'role_set__person_role',
        )
```

Then one can use `film.role_set` to access `through` model instances (in this case, `Role`).