# Django: prefetch_related() with m2m through relationship v2

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

I know there is already a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35093204/django-prefetch-related-with-m2m-through-relationship), but I think my case is a bit more complicated because I have a different entry point.

These are my models:

```
class m_Interaction(models.Model):
  fk_ip = models.ForeignKey('m_IP', related_name="interactions")

class m_User(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class m_IP(models.Model):
  fk_user = models.ForeignKey('m_User', related_name="ips" )

class m_Feature(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  m2m_interaction = models.ManyToManyField(m_Interaction, related_name='features', through='m_Featurescore')

class m_Featurescore(models.Model):
  score = models.FloatField(null=False)
  fk_interaction = models.ForeignKey(m_Interaction, related_name='featurescore')
  fk_feature = models.ForeignKey(m_Feature, related_name='featurescore')
```

I start with m_User, follow the reverse relationship over m_IP to the Interactions (m_Interaction). Then I want to get every m_Featurescore.score for each Interaction for a specific instance of m_Feature.

My working query to access at least all interactions in a performant way:

```
m_User.objects.all().prefetch_related('ips__interactions')
```

But I can't figure out the correct 'prefetch_related'-statement to access the m_Featurescore.score like this

```
db_obj_interaction.featurescore.get(fk_feature=db_obj_feature).score
```

without making a lot of queries.

I already tried almost all combinations of the following:

```
'ips__interactions__features__featurescore'
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: How about 'ips__interactions__featurescore'?
Also, using the get() method means you're forcing the ORM to make a query. You need to use the all() method in order to take advantage of the prefetch. If you need filtering, use a Prefetch() object.

Comment: @noamk perfect. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question with the help of noamk in the comments:

I didn't consider that the get()-method in `db_obj_interaction.featurescore.get(fk_feature=db_obj_feature).score` will issue a new query everytime it's called (it's kinda obvious now).

Therefore I simply restructured my code and now I don't need get() anymore and can use the benefit of the prefetch.

If somebody still needs to filter the [Prefetch()-object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-objects) should be used as suggested by noamk